# Django: call REST API through a view instead of Postman

Tags: django

I have a working python code on my desktop that prints and makes PDFs perfectly. All I want to do is use that code and use Django to allow users to enter a value.

My code uses `docusign` API to call data. I use `postman` which needs a key and other parameters to use the API.  The value entered by my user will determine what data they get.

What I think I have to do is rewrite my code, put it somewhere, then turn it into a view. The view will be sent to template.

Edit -

My code:

```
# Get Envelope Data- use account ID from above
# Get Todays Date, Daily Setting
day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + accountId + "/envelopes"
# if Envelope is completed
querystring = {"from_date": Date, "status": "completed"}


headers = {
    'X-DocuSign-Authentication': "{\"Username\":\""+ email +"\",\"Password\":\""+Password+"\",\"IntegratorKey\": \""+IntegratorKey+"\"}",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "e53ceaba-512d-467b-9f95-1b89f6f65211"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
envelopes = response.text
```

Sorry, let me try again. I currently have a `python3` program on my desktop. I run it with `idle` and everything is how I want it.

What I want to do with Django is use this code to print its outputs on a webpage and have the user download it’s additional `csv` file output. I have managed to make a Django localhost and I am stuck at that point. I do not know how to use my `python3` code to run to webpage.

The code is made up of API calls, I use postman to help me with sending the right parameters. I will add a picture of code. All I want is for user to enter value such as `accountID` so that the API can complete the request and give them data for their own request.

Comment: You have to be more specific with questions to ask for help on SO

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post, idk why the date is huge in my example code but that doesn’t matter rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you a overview of how this could work with Django.

You could have a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) to obtain the users `account_id`.

```
class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    account_id = forms.IntegerField()
```

You could display this form through a generic [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) (see also [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views)):

```
class AccountView(views.FormView):
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'account.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # here you make your request to the external API
        account_id = form.cleaned_data['account_id']
        url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/" + account_id + "/envelopes"
        headers = ...
        querystring = ...
        resp = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

        ctx = {
            'result': resp.text,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'result.html', ctx)
```

I don't show the template `account.html` here. You will have to figure that one out yourself; the links I provided should point you in the right direction.

Now, what remains to be determined is what exactly the method `form_valid` should return. The code I showed renders a template with the API call response in the context, so in your template `result.html` you could display the result data any way you like.

You mentioned downloading a CSV file as well. That could be a different view, probably triggered by a link or button in `result.html`.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing my question and answering. What you did is more than enough to send me in the right direction. I’ve read the link but I need to re-read it a few more time to fully grasp it. My code also uses json.loads and json.dumps to parse the response. Would you recommend just putting that before the “ctx” part. Also I saw someone hide keys for the api in settings.py Would you do that ?

Comment: @B.D putting your URL (`demo.docusign.net`) and API keys in `settings.py` is good practice to have all the config in one place, in case you have to modify/renew the keys at some point. This also allows you to use the keys in multiple views without writting them twice.

Comment: @B.D yes, its a good idea to use `'result': json.loads(resp.text)` in the view, so that you pass a dict into your template `result.html`. That makes it easier for you in the template.

Comment: thank you , I will try this out and hopefully get it to work soon. I have a lot to learn